# How to pass table variable from FunctionA to FunctionB, and return table variable from FunctionB to FunctionA?

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

As title,I have written a simple code as following.

`functionA` : pass the result (table variable) to functionB

`functionB` : reassign the field name and return the result (table variable) to functionA

```
create function functionA(
    @Type nvarchar(max) 
    , @isArray bit = 0
)
returns @tempTable table (
    FieldId nvarchar(4000)
    , FieldName nvarchar(4000)
    , FieldType nvarchar(4000)
    , IsArray bit)
as
begin
    declare @tempTableA table (
        FieldId nvarchar(4000)
        , FieldName nvarchar(4000)
        , FieldType nvarchar(4000)
        , IsArray bit) 

    insert @tempTableA 
    select 
        *
    from 
        TableA
    where 
            @isArray = 1 and @Type='TypeA'
    
    insert @tempTable 
    select * from functionB(@tempTableA)

    return 

end
go
```

```
create function functionB(
    --How to get the table variable from functionA?
    @tempTableA table
)
returns @tempTableB table (
    FieldId nvarchar(4000)
    , FieldName nvarchar(4000)
    , FieldType nvarchar(4000)
    , IsArray bit)
as
begin
    insert @tempTableB
    select 
        FieldId [Id]
            , FieldName [Name]
            , FieldType [Type]
            , IsArray Array
    from 
        @tempTableA
    
    return 

end
go
```

When I expect the functionB will get error message :

> The syntax near the keyword 'table' is incorrect.
>
> The data table variable "@tempTableB" must be declared.
>
> The data table variable "@tempTableA" must be declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table variable should be `READONLY`. Let me show an example:

At first you should create User Defined Table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tp_List] AS TABLE(
    [Val] [int] NULL
)
GO
```

Then use this table type into your function:

```
GO 
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionB( 
@TableName tp_List READONLY
)
RETURNS @mt table (a int)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @mt
    SELECT * FROM @TableName
    RETURN
END
GO
```

And usage:

```
DECLARE @tbl tp_List
INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    Val
)
VALUES
(50)
SELECT * FROM FunctionB(@tbl)
```

OUTPUT:

```
a
50
```

Comment: Should `@tempTableA` must be User-Defined Table Types?
 `create type TableType as table (...)`